# How to suppress repair warnings dialogs and open word documents using interop.word package in net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, interop, ms-word

In my ASP.NET windows application, i have to manipulate Word 2007 document.So, i am using Microsoft.Interop.Word package for that work.For normal document it is working correctly...

At the same i have to open some type of corrupted file also.for example,header/footer losses,alignment losses...

So, i was opened files like that below...

```
wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref paramSourceDocPath, OpenAndRepair:true);
```

So, Now it is working fine with above mentioned case except header/footer lose case.

When i open the document it displays this below mentioned dialog box for confirmation.So, I have to pass this dialog without showing for user confirmation...

[image]

After clicking the close button in the dialog box then the document opened correctly...

So,Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: If you have access to the Windows registry, you can make certain changes to it, to prevent  the "Show Repairs" dialog from appearing. [Here is a reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903740).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to suppress this Show Repairs dialog, you can use the Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog method to open your word document instead.